# How do I rotate a gtk treeview to display a column horizontally?

Tags: c++, user-interface, treeview, gtk

I have an odd application where I need to display a list of text horizontally in my application. For vertical lists I have used GTK treeviews with a single column and would like to do the same here, but I can't figure out how to display the column horizontally.  I can rotate the text in the column correctly:

```
pango_font_description_set_gravity(pFontDescription, PANGO_GRAVITY_WEST);
```

Unfortunately, the treeview wants to lay out the cells vertically.  Any thoughts?